# Simple Desktop App in Python is closing in 1 sec

Tags: python

I searched for the answer of my question on stackoverflow. I found some answers but couldn't solve my problems.

When I write my code (shared below) on PyCharm, I get the proper results. But I would like to write my codes in notepad. I'm saving it as "py" file.

When I try to double-click on the file and try to run it, it is opening in 1 sec and then closing again. I can see black screen for 1 second.

This is likely quite a simple situation but I don't seem to find a solution.

```
while True:

    first_value=input("first value (to exit press "q"):")

    if first_value == "q":
        break
    second_value=input("second value:")

    try:
        digit1=int(first_value)
        digit2=int(second_value)
        print(digit1,"/",digit2,"=",digit1/digit2)
    except(ValueError,ZeroDivisionError):
        print("An Error Occured!")
```

Comment: There's a quotation error on the first line

Comment: Try to run you script from terminal: `python script_name.py` . Then you will see all outputs.

Comment: Also, don't use notepad over Jupyter or Pycharm. It performs syntax checking for your. At least use some other text editor with a linter than Notepad

Comment: It's running fine, it finishes and exits. If you want to see the output then run it from a shell/cmd.

Comment: `first_value=input("first value (to exit press 'q'):")` - note single quote around q

Comment: the error was about espace sequences not about cmd. But thank you for the cooperation :)

Answer (score 1):

There is quotation error in first line `first_value=input("first value (to exit press "q"):")`

you can use `'...'`: `first_value=input('first value (to exit press "q"):')` or escape quotes by `\`: `first_value=input("first value (to exit press \"q\"):")`

Comment: God! Jeslin you are awesome! thank you very much buddy! You helped an amateur coder and you made me happy! Hope I will become an adept on developing and help everyone :)